# what is a "federation issue" in a bug reporting system

Tags: bug-tracking, definition, issue-tracking, federation

There are different categories in bug tracking systems. One of these categories is "federation". What does it really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be this would refer to tasks that are required to "federate" (bring together) other systems or tools. So maybe things like SSO (single sign-on) or an enterprise wide "portal" that aggregates other tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is to do with user authentication etc... See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity